# Having trouble encoding dataset array

Tags: python, arrays, machine-learning, scikit-learn, encoding

Dataset: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jlKp7JR9Ewujv445QgT1kZpH5868fhXFFrA3ovWxS_0/edit?usp=sharing

I've been trying to deploy the ensemble method from sklearn to a small dataset I have linked above. For some reason I keep receiving this error.

```
ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (9, 56) instead.
```

This is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy import array

from sklearn import datasets, metrics
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

cbdata = pd.read_excel("C:/Users/Andrew/cbupdated2.xlsx")

print(cbdata)
print(cbdata.describe())
df = cbdata.columns

print(df)

x = cbdata
y = cbdata.fundingstatus

xshape = x.shape
yshape = y.shape

shapes = xshape, yshape
print(shapes)

size = x.size, y.size
print(size)


###Problem ENCODING DATA
      
##Label encoder
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
integer_encoded = label_encoder.fit_transform(x)
print(integer_encoded)


scaler = StandardScaler()
X_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(x)
print(X_scaled)

###Problm block
ec = OneHotEncoder()


X_encoded = cbdata.apply(lambda col: ec.fit_transform(col.astype(str)), axis=0, result_type='expand')
X_encoded2 = X_encoded.shape

print(X_encoded2)
```

Any help and/or suggestions on getting encoder to work, so I can use the ensemble method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LabelEncoder` is meant for encoding target variables, not features. See also [this post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/39317/difference-between-ordinalencoder-and-labelencoder/64177)

You should use `OrdinalEncoder` on the categorical columns you want to transform, because I see some of your columns have floats and strings. So for example to transform `company` and `industry` :

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder

Cols = ["company","industry"]

integer_encoded = OrdinalEncoder().fit_transform(x[Cols])
```

Comment: so could I use ```ordinal encoder``` on every column including non-catagorical ? and could I keep my target variable (cbdata.fundingstatus) as 'y' ?

Comment: it's not useful to use ordinal encoder on numerical columns. yes you can keep your target variable

Comment: got it & leave numerical columns alone or apply ``onehotencoder``` to them ?